# How to store output of select statement spooled from oracle db in multi dimentional array variable of powershell?

Tags: arrays, oracle, powershell

I am storing the data from a select statement into a powershell variable. How do I make the variable to be a multi dimentional array.

```
$sql1=@"
  set echo off;
  set pagesize 0
  set head off;
  set feedback off;
  set pause off;
  set verify off;
  set trimspool on;
  set linesize 15000;
  set colsep '';
  set termout off;
select * From employee where 
rownum<4;
"@
```

Execute the above statement  using sqlplus and storing the data in variable `$output1`

```
$output1 = $sql1 |sqlplus -silent $username/$password@$tnsalias
```

The type of variable I get is

```
echo $output1.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                    
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                    
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

I am able to access the output based on the array index like below

```
    echo $output1[0]
    echo $output1[1]
```

The content of all the columns are stored as string.

```
echo $output1[0].getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                    
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

How to make the $output1 as a multi dimentional array so that specific column data can be accessed in the below way.

```
$output1[0][0]  --- row1, column1 data
$output1[0][1]  --- row1, column2 data
$output1[1][1]  --- row2, column2 data
```

Comment: `set colsep ,` to output as comma-separated values, then pipe output to `ConvertFrom-Csv`. You may need to set `head on` and `headsep ,` as well to get correct header names